# How do I save new data to a JSON file in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "header": [
    "[[1, 26, 242, 151]]",
    "[[1, 26, 242, 152]]"
  ],
  "[[1, 26, 242, 151]]": {
    "key": "73E5-16AC-260C-3C8C"
  },
  "[[1, 26, 242, 152]]": {
    "key": "73E5-16AC-260C-3C8D"
  }
}
```

So now let's assume I want to add a third object to the file that looks like this:

```
  "[[1, 26, 242, 153]]": {
    "key": "73E5-16AC-260C-3C8E"
  }
```

How can I write that that to my JSON file while keeping the correct formatting and all, and adding the name of the object to the array of the header?

And I want to change the `key` value of `"[[1, 26, 242, 151]]"` from `"73E5-16AC-260C-3C8C"` to `"84F6-27BD-361D-4D9D"`.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but something along the lines of:

```
// here you parse the json object into a class
TwoObjectsJson twoObjs = TwoObjectsJson.fromJson(jsonFile);
// here you parse the class into another class
ThreeObjectsJson threeObjs = ThreeObjectsJson.fromTwoObjectJson(twoObjs, "[[1, 26, 242, 153]]", "73E5-16AC-260C-3C8E");
// here you get back your json string
final myJsonStr = threeObjs.toJson();
```

Then to change the key value of the first object, you've access to it:

```
threeObjs.value.changeValue("84F6-27BD-361D-4D9D");
```

Another approach would be your json object to have a list for the objects it contains, instead of having them one after each other.

Comment: In case I didn't misread your post, I already have such a list with my header. In case I misread, please clarify. I don't quite get how join those objects and add the name of the third one to the header. In case you already wrote it, please help me out, I'm still a bloody beginner

Comment: @VincentGuttmann I'm trying to help you out. Did you read already the [Serializing JSON inside model classes](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes) official doc? Then you know you can decode your json string into a data class (my TwoObjectsJson in the example). At this point it's a normal class, with 3 fields. So you can parse it into another class (my ThreeObjectsJson in the example) and merge it with the additional object you want to add. This normal class has 4 fields instead. Once parsed, you can encode it back into a string

Comment: Note: best would be if you can change the struct of your json file, so that it would contain "header" and then a collection of "items", because then it would be much easier to add any other item you want to the collection. But this wasn't part of your question

Comment: I think I got what you mean: containing the objects inside the itself, right?

Comment: @VincentGuttmann which part of my code is not clear? I can try to explain the code even better or more verbosely if you need, just point me out to where you have no clear understanding